# Gem's aren't working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using some gem in my application, but I'm some problems whith this.

In a form, I'm using gem cocoon for create nested fields, I'm using datatable for sorting columns too.

But these gem aren't not working in production.

I put the gem out assets group, I tried use: rake assets:precompile --trace before to execute the application, but still don't working.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.16'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.14'

# Autenticação
gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.3.0'

# Autorização
gem 'cancan'

# Anexos
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'

# Mailer
gem 'mail', '~> 2.5.4'

# Custom select 
gem "bootstrap-select-rails", "~> 1.3.0"

# 
gem 'whenever', :require => false

# Nested fields
gem 'cocoon'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do

  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.0.3'

end
gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.12.0'

gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', github: 'rweng/jquery-datatables-rails'

gem 'less-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.1.1'

# twitter bootstrap css & javascript toolkit
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails', '~> 3.0.3'

# twitter bootstrap helpers gem, e.g., alerts etc...
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails-helpers'
```

config/production.rb

Curriculum::Application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

```
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compile = true

  #config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
  #config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

 end
```

application.js

```
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require jquery.ui.all
 //= require jquery.ui.tabs
 //= require jquery.ui.tabs.min
 //= require bootstrap-tabs
 //= require interns
 //= require systems_analysts
 //= require generics
 //= require file_field
 //= require bootstrap-filestyle
 //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 //= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 //= require cocoon
```

Log

```
 => Rails 3.2.16 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
 => Call with -d to detach
 => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
 [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you      really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
 [2014-02-04 11:08:45] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
 [2014-02-04 11:08:45] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [x86_64-linux]
 [2014-02-04 11:08:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2567 port=3000
 Started GET "/hr_curriculum_generics/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-04 11:08:45 -0200
 Processing by HrCurriculumGenericsController#new as HTML
   Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.7ms)
   Rendered hr_curriculum_generics/_generic_company_fields.html.erb (2.0ms)
   Rendered hr_curriculum_generics/_form.html.erb (144.0ms)
   Rendered hr_curriculum_generics/new.html.erb within layouts/application (151.7ms)
 Completed 200 OK in 382.1ms (Views: 286.4ms | ActiveRecord: 4.6ms)
 [2014-02-04 11:08:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
 Started GET "/assets/cerulean-e95335988bef420c8d08256a4348651d.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-04 11:08:46 -0200
 Served asset /cerulean-e95335988bef420c8d08256a4348651d.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
 [2014-02-04 11:08:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-     length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
 Started GET "/assets/application-112486149e37a46f8edf68319a3cc0da.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-04 11:08:46 -0200
 Served asset /application-112486149e37a46f8edf68319a3cc0da.js - 304 Not Modified (107ms)
 Started GET "/assets/logo-scaled-3757028be58a8cc4ac22912194a7f4e3.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-04 11:08:46 -0200
 Served asset /logo-scaled-3757028be58a8cc4ac22912194a7f4e3.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
 [2014-02-04 11:08:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
 [2014-02-04 11:08:46] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set      content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

Comment: which error you gave, and which rails you've use?

Comment: Hi, I'm using rails 3.2.16 and ruby 1.9.3, any errors show, just nothing happens

Comment: what do you mean: nothing happens?

Comment: In a form, if I click in "add nested fields", nothing happends, any fields show(cocoon). In tables, if I click in name of column(sortable column), the table still the same

Comment: I updated my question with log =]

Comment: Are there any warnings in the browser?

Comment: Nops, any warnings =/

Comment: Since you ave run the prod server locally, just store prod config to other place, replace prod config with the devel, and try to run. and say results.

Comment: What does the browser log/console say? It looks like this could be a Javascript problem.

Comment: I replaced prod config with dev conf, works now =], thanks everyone